# how to check open file in other process or not?

Tags: node.js

I use simple script  for writing in file between node.js process:

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('test');
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
        stream.write(progress_percents);
});
```

In log I see error "to many open file". How to write to file only if this file not using other processes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've diagnosed the problem incorrectly. The `too many open files` error means that too many files are opened by *this* process.

Comment: But how to close stream after write ?